# Discord.js unable to login after using Client#destroy()

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```js
switch (command[0])
{
  case 'restart':
    if(msg.author.id == config["owner"]){
      msg.channel.send(preEmbed('clientRestart'));
      client.destroy();
      client.login(config["token"]);
    }
    break;
}
```

this causes the error `DiscordjsError: Request to use token, but token was unavailable to the client.`

anyone know the cause / fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [discord.js' github repo](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/9c915d1e0a4bb3fcdc0a022b9ef3aaf3f1556bd7/src/util/Constants.js#L66), you get that message when you don't provide a token, so make sure you are providing the token correctly.

Comment: what do you mean by "requesting a new token"?

Comment: If you go to `https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/BOT_ID/bot` you can regenerate your token.

Just try to use a new token to see if that would fix your issue

Comment: console.log `config["token"]` before and after `client.destroy()`, does it show the token in both?

Comment: tried, magically doesn't output error anymore with or without console.log, i haven't changed anything besides that. thanks